# Tableau: Show Table with Average Sales per Weekday?

Tags: tableau-api

I have two fields [date] and [sales].

I want to display this in a table but have another column which returns the average sales per corresponding weekday?

example:

date,sales,weekday,avg per weekday

01/01/2018, 1100, monday, 1000

01/02/2018, 2000, tuesday, 2000

01/03/2018, 900, wednesday, 750

...

01/08/2018, 900, monday, 1000

01/09/2018, 2000, tuesday, 2000

01/03/2018, 600, wednesday, 750

I already have a calculated field that shows what day (monday, tuesday, etc.) it is per date but I'm having trouble thinking of what formula to use to be able to return the average monday sale, tuesday sale, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep track of your highest level of granularity (Date) and at the same time show another kind of granularity (weekday) in the same viz, you shuold probably take a look to L(evel) O(f) D(etail) functions (LOD).

In your example, you can try something like this:

[image]

Comment: Glad to be helpful.